# Construct generic class of concrete class from interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have a WCF service which accepts any entity which implements an interface. When it receives one of these entities I would like to publish an event i.e.

```
public void Receive(IFruit fruit)
{
      messageHub.Publish(new FruitReceived<IFruit>(fruit));
}
```

However I would like to reify the interface so instead of everything that handles fruit subscribing to the event `FruitReceived<IFruit>` they can subscribe to only the type they're interested in such as `FruitReceived<Apple>`.

Currently I can do this through some lengthy reflection:

```
var fruitType = fruit.GetType();
var evt = typeof(FruitReceived<>)
    .MakeGenericType(fruitType)
    .GetConstructor(fruitType)
    .Invoke(fruit);
```

This is a bit of a performance hit (even with caching the constructors) and also hard to read.

I was hoping that there's a simpler way to achieve this? I have spent so much time thinking about this solution that it's the only one I can come up with.

For reference the publish method simplifies to something like this:

```
public void Publish<TEvent>(TEvent evt)
{
    if(_subscriptions.ContainsKey(typeof(TEvent))
    {
        IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>> handlers = _subscriptions[typeof(TEvent)];

        foreach(var handler in handlers)
        {
            handler.HandleEvent(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem seems to be that you're receiving an instance of `IFruit` but downstream you want to distinguish between different concrete types.

The benefit of casting a class as an interface it implements is that consumers only need to know what the *declared* type is. They know it's an `IFruit` and that's all they need to know. As soon as they need to know more than that the benefit is reduced.

In other words, if you care at all about the difference between an `Apple` and an `Orange` then why cast it as an `IFruit`? Of course there are differences between implementations, but those differences - even the existence of different implementations - should be transparent to anything that depends on an `IFruit`.

There's no perfectly neat way to handle this. If you're not creating the generic type (as in your post) then you're doing this:

```
if(fruit is Apple)
```

There's going to be type creation or type inspection no matter what.

You could move the problem. Have a single event handler that handles `FruitReceived<IFruit>`. Then that event handler creates the more specific event type and re-raises it so that the more specific event handler can catch it. That way you can have event handlers specific to `Apple`, `Orange`, etc.

It's not perfect but it moves the problem from where the event is getting raised to another class that facilitates raising the more specific event type.

Another reason why this is beneficial is that your design allows for multiple event handlers. So conceivably you could raise `FruitEvent<IFruit>` where the concrete type is an `Apple`, so you want an apple-specific event handler, but you also want a generic `IFruit` event handler to execute. If you convert your event to `FruitEvent<Apple>` before raising it then you won't execute the generic event handler.

Comment: I originally was using different entry points for each type of `IFruit` but it was getting unwieldy. As it's a WCF service I would have to add create/delete methods to the contract, update the contract implementation and then because it's a duplex service do both to the callback side too. All that before I could begin implementing the new type of `IFruit`. Also because this is a WCF service I also couldn't use generics or overloading in the contract to make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This can usually be solved with the visitor pattern. But it requires some extensive changes, starting with `IFruit`:

```
interface IFruitVisitor {
    void Visit(Apple apple);
    void Visit(Banana banana);
    // ... you need a method for each fruit
}

interface IFruit {
    Accept(IFruitVisitor visitor);
}
```

Then your fruits must implement that method:

```
class Apple : IFruit {
    public void Accept(IFruitVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}
class Banana : IFruit {
    public void Accept(IFruitVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);
}
```

And you can have a special visitor for your case:

```
class CreateFruitReceivedFruitVisitor : IFruitVisitor {
    public object FruitReceived { get; private set; }
    public void Visit(Banana banana) => FruitReceived = new FruitReceived<Banana>(banana);
    public void Visit(Apple apple) => FruitReceived = new FruitReceived<Apple>(apple);
}
```

Then, just use it in your original method:

```
public void Receive(IFruit fruit)
{
    var visitor = new CreateFruitReceivedFruitVisitor();
    fruit.Accept(visitor);
    messageHub.Publish(visitor.FruitReceived);
}
```

You need to weight in the benefits and costs of this solution. Even though it can be faster than the reflection version you showed, I believe it's much more unwieldy.